# Statistics-Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics

The pdf of the gamma distribution with parameters r=5/2 and gamma=3 is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
kx^{3/2} e^{-3x}, & x>0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $k=12\sqrt{3/\pi}$.

So far, I know that I need to set up an integral from 0 to infinity of kx^(3/2)*e^(-3x) dx=1.  Then I pull the k out in front because it is a constant.  so I have k* the Integral of x^(3/2)*e^(-3x)dx.  Do I need to use u-substitution to complete the integral to show that k=12sqrt(3/pi)?  I know I need to use the notion that gamma(1/2)=sqrt(pi) also, but I figured that would be after I integrated.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^\infty kx^\frac{3}{2}e^{-3x}dx=1
$$

For X ~ Gamma ($\alpha,\beta$),  $~~f(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}$

Thus, in your problem:

$$
\int_0^\infty kx^{\frac{5}{2}-1}e^{-3x}dx=1
$$

$$
k \frac{\Gamma(5/2)}{3^{5/2}} \int_0^\infty\frac{3^{5/2}}{\Gamma(5/2)} x^{\frac{5}{2}-1}e^{-3x}dx=1
$$

Thus, the integral is equal to 1, and its pretty straightforward to solve for k.

Also note: $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$

Hope this helps